# Problem with google_maps_flutter (GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to test the google_maps_flutter Package on an Android virtual device using AVD i followed installing guide and from this link [package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)
but it's freezing and gives this on the console

```
W/ziparchive(21894): Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000f/DynamiteLoader.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive(21894): Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000f/DynamiteLoader.dm': No such file or directory
I/DynamiteModule(21894): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203115000
I/DynamiteModule(21894): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 203115000
V/DynamiteModule(21894): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/System  (21894): ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
D/nativeloader(21894): Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk . target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~kJOpjF2ETgCTif3gFapMfg==/com.google.android.gms-Fb2_EFPheR4lqaAgYU9FWA==/lib/x86_64:/data/app/~~kJOpjF2ETgCTif3gFapMfg==/com.google.android.gms-Fb2_EFPheR4lqaAgYU9FWA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
W/ziparchive(21894): Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000013/MapsDynamite.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive(21894): Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000013/MapsDynamite.dm': No such file or directory
I/Google Maps Android API(21894): Google Play services client version: 12451000
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(21894): Compat change id reported: 183155436; UID 10159; state: ENABLED
I/Google Maps Android API(21894): Google Play services package version: 232414047
I/Google Maps Android API(21894): Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000
D/MapsInitializer(21894): loadedRenderer: LEGACY
D/zzcb    (21894): preferredRenderer: null
I/Google Maps Android API(21894): Google Play services package version: 232414047
I/Google Maps Android API(21894): Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(21894): Compat change id reported: 210923482; UID 10159; state: ENABLED
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(21894): Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10159; state: ENABLED
W/Google Maps Android API(21894): Deprecation notice: In a future release, indoor will no longer be supported on satellite, hybrid or terrain type maps. Even where indoor is not supported, isIndoorEnabled() will continue to return the value that has been set via setIndoorEnabled(), as it does now. By default, setIndoorEnabled is 'true'. The API release notes (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases) will let you know when indoor support becomes unavailable on those map types.
I/PlatformViewsController(21894): Using hybrid composition for platform view: 0
E/GoogleMapController(21894): Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted
I/bb      (21894): Successfully registered with Phenotype.
E/Google Maps Android API(21894): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API(21894): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
E/Google Maps Android API(21894): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
E/Google Maps Android API(21894): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
E/Google Maps Android API(21894):   API Key: {AIzaSyCNrkk88TToyEyiaycGfsLD5mCfx2FpHZ8}
E/Google Maps Android API(21894):   Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): E1:F7:E6:00:C4:DE:0A:15:11:FF:B8:C4:8B:3E:C8:A1:5D:C1:0B:97;com.example.applicationservice
W/DynamiteModule(21894): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule(21894): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:7
I/DynamiteModule(21894): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 7
W/ziparchive(21894): Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000012/GoogleCertificates.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive(21894): Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000012/GoogleCertificates.dm': No such file or directory
I/SnapshotHandler(21894): Unable to retrieve flag snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.example.applicationservice, using defaults.
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894): Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.example.applicationservice, may result in stale flags.
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.applicationservice, sha256=[43c00560db79c723e17bcc8fc37e1673565ea9d2ac0e6968be2d6a6564fe1367], atk=false, ver=232414047.true (go/gsrlt)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at m.ajx.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):3)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at m.ajx.get(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at m.alh.g(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at m.yz.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):1)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at m.zb.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):0)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.applicationservice, sha256=[43c00560db79c723e17bcc8fc37e1673565ea9d2ac0e6968be2d6a6564fe1367], atk=false, ver=232414047.true (go/gsrlt)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3011)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at m.fe.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at m.ry.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):4)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at m.jl.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at m.kj.t(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at m.kj.u(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):3)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at m.kj.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):2)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at m.kn.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):78)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(21894):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

this is what i have add to install the package on the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
    
        android:label="applicationservice"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
            <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="{AIzaSyCN........sLD5mCfx2FpHZ8}"/>
    </application>
    
</manifest>
```

and this is the bundle.gradle meta-data

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw  GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.applicationservice"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.applicationservice"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'


}
```

Code (MainPage.dart):-

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller =
      Completer<GoogleMapController>();

  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  static const CameraPosition _kLake = CameraPosition(
      bearing: 192.8334901395799,
      target: LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792),
      tilt: 59.440717697143555,
      zoom: 19.151926040649414);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle defaultStyle = TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'almarailight', fontSize: 20.0);
    TextStyle linkStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.blue);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(33, 33, 33, 1),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          'الرئيسية',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'cairoBold',
            fontSize: 32.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            shadows: <Shadow>[
              Shadow(
                offset: Offset(2, 2),
                blurRadius: 1.0,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
              ),
              Shadow(
                offset: Offset(2, 2),
                blurRadius: 1.0,
                color: Color.fromARGB(124, 0, 0, 0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xff7c94b6),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage('https://i.imgur.com/nu9p9t3.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.settings,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              // do something
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Form(
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              GoogleMap(
                mapType: MapType.hybrid,
                initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                },
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your AVD include Play Store?   If not, can you select an avd that includes it and try again?